# Printing UTF8 extended characters in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I try this code and it works very well:

```
package code;



    public class TestClass
    {
        public static String myName="محمد mohammed";


        public static String getMyName()
        {
            return myName;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            System.out.println(getMyName());
        }

    }
```

and I get this result :

> محمد mohammed

But when I try to call from servlet in same package and project :

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {

...
System.out.println(TestClass.getMyName());          
...
    }// END DO GET
```

I got this result:

> ???? mohammed

Moreover, I tried to print directly from the servlet and I got '?' for any Arabic letter.

Note: 
In two files I use : UTF-8

**

> It is solved by changing server encoding. see below:

**

> Go to (if use Eclipse): 
>   1- Servers. 
>   2- open the server. 
>   3- find : open lunch configuration then open it. 
>   4- Go to Common. 
>   5- Change Encoding.

Comment: How are you "printing"?

Comment: System.out.println(....);

Comment: This looks like an encoding problem.  Can you try this: `String myName = new String("محمد mohammed".getBytes(), "UTF-8");`

Comment: Thank you, I tried that : String myName = new String("محمد mohammed".getBytes(), "UTF-8"); But still I got '?' mark

Comment: Could it be that you are not telling the java compiler that the encoding is UTF8 when you are compiling the servlet?

Comment: Calling `TestClass.getMyName();` on its own won't do anything; what are you doing with the result of that in your `doGet` method?

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard How can I do that ?

Comment: @Saposhiente I put the call inside :: System.out.println(...) ::

Comment: Instead of solving, I would use the occasion for a Logger, for instance there already is a [`getServletContext().log("...")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#log%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: It depends how you're compiling.. if directly from the command line, javac has an "encoding" parameter.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard I use Eclipse.

Comment: Thank all. it is solved.

Comment: @محمدالتويجري Could you post your solution as an answer? Someone in the future willl probably stumble upon the same problem and will be happy to have a working solution ;)